# How to stop generating .vbs file when .doc is converted to ..pdf using document4j

Tags: java, pdf, doc, documents4j

I have written this code and when I run the program it runs successfully, but it also print .vbs file along with this and I don't want that file as it will load my file system.

```
 File fs=new File("D:/parser/samrudha-kelkar.docx");  
        File file=new File("D:/test.pdf");

        IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder().build();

         Future<Boolean> conversion = converter
                 .convert(fs).as(DocumentType.MS_WORD)
                 .to(file).as(DocumentType.PDF)
                 .prioritizeWith(1000) // optional
                 .schedule();
```

Comment: why not delete the folder after pdf generation?

Comment: that we can do, but it's better to avoid two unnecessary call of first creating it and deleting it, and I don't know by what name it will be created.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `converter.shutdown()`, documents4j should clean up after itself and leave you with an empty folder which you can safely delete. Note that any running job needs to terminate before the folder will be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder()
                    .baseFolder(new File("D:/parser/tmp"))
                    .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .processTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();

FileUtils.deleteDirectory("D:/parser/tmp");
```

I think that you have to create .vbs files in order to do the conversion